# Lazy evaluation of .dot or other theano function

Tags: python, lazy-evaluation, symbolic-math, theano

I am very new at python and theano so this question may be silly.

I've read in documentation that .dot produces symbolic tensor. I am debugging some program right now and I can't see TensorVariable without any container or anything and I don't know how to get the values from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't really possible to get a value from a symbolic variable because they don't have a value; instead they stand in for a value that is provided later.

Consider the following example:

```
x = theano.tensor.matrix()
y = theano.tensor.matrix()
z = theano.dot(x, y)
f = theano.function(inputs=[x, y], outputs=z)
a = numpy.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])
b = numpy.array([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]])
c = f(a, b)
```

Here, `x` and `y` are symbolic matrices. They don't have a value but they stand-in for some value that will be provided after the computation is compiled and executed. `a`, `b`, and `c` are concrete matrices with values. The `f = theano.function(...)` line compiles the computation and the `c = f(...)` executes that function, providing the value called `a` for `x` and providing the value called `b` for `y`; the return value, `c`, takes on the value computed by the symbolic expression `z`.

Comment: Thank you for answer. Just one thing. If X and Y have some values, Z has still nothing until f is triggered?

Comment: None of `x`, `y`, or `z` have a value until `f` is executed.